# Add images to an existing database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database (mysql) that I have put together and have displayed on a page.
What I would like to do now is add an image to all the entries(a different image for each entry).

I have some code that randomly picks a entry and shows some columns. I've Google'd the thing I want to achieve and the results have shown me that I should use some file path to the image for each entry. The research I made I found it unsufficient as information, so I decided to ask here.

What I do not want to use:

- Blob

So my question is, what is the optimal solution to set a random picture on each entry in my table?

Comment: _..so I thought I would ask the question here..._ What question?`

Comment: *...also have google the question and can not find an information on this...* I find this assertion highly dubious.

Answer (score 0):

I personally dislike BLOBs, because they increase the database size, and the handling is not good if you can only work with queries.

It is not clear if the pictures you want are external or local.

**If external**, then just make a new column and fill it with an URI that contains the image.

ALERT TABLE xxx ADD COLUMN image varchar(200) NULL;

and then, with a loop you can fill the table. Therefore, write a temporary PHP script, just for this one case.

**If local**, then I would simply create a directory, e.g. "product_images", and the folder's contents are database + ".jpg" . If all pictures are JPEG, then you do not need to change your table structure at all. Just modify your PHP script that it displays the image "product_images/".$row['id'].".jpg" . If you have JPEG and PNG together, either add a database column that contains the file extention, or detect it via `file_exists()`.

To add the image files into the directory, I would also create a script just for this single purpose. Write a PHP script or Bash script, or whatever language you want, that reads the MySQL table, and copies/generates a file called .jpg .

Comment: What exactly? Please post the code you have and what you want to do exactly? And are the pics local or external?